# EF Core and caching of results

Tags: entity-framework, .net-core

I'm working on an Websocket application. When the client connects to the server, the websocket session get one dbcontext from dependency injection

```
Services.AddDbContext<Db>
```

This dbcontext will be the same for the whole websocket session. The problem is that the dbcontext will cache results. So if the websocket session is open for for example two hours and its reading the same data twice, while the data has been changed outside that dbcontext, the dbContext will give give invalid data back as response for the query. (the cached result from last query). There is serveral examples on how to avoid this, but it has to be done on every query. This is not really practical and somewhere in the code it might be forgotten and you have a chance to get invalid data.

Is there someway to permanently disable caching?

Answer (score 1):

I think that you try use Entity Framewor in a very wrong way, DbContext is not supposed to work this way and it is not a cache per say, although it keeps some data in memory for you.

In your case I would suggest to either

- Query The database every time as you suggested.

Or even better

- Take advantage of proper caching mechanisms.

The decision if you should use sql server or a caching mechanism is based on how long you want to keep the data and how often you want to query them. If it is permanent and not query so often then it is sql server. If it is a couple of hours and you query very often it is better caching.

As a caching mechanism you can use:

1. The default [MemoryCache](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.caching.memorycache?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1), but it has quite limited functionality and it is restricted to the application level, so if you run multiple instyance of yor application this solution will not work out.
2. A distributed cache solution, like Redis, which supports a lot of functionality and you can connect many instances of your applications.

Comment: Thank you for your sugestions. I want to disable all caching. Updates are comming also from other services and also from other machines. Its a job for sql server to cache to memory - not some "smart ass things in the application" - my opinion.

Comment: It does not matter at all, distributed cache will work fine. The answer if you should use sql server or a caching mechanism is based on how long you want to keep the data and how often you want to query them. If it is permanent and not query so often then it is sql server. If it is a couple of hours and you query very often it is better caching.

Comment: ok, thank you. that might be an option later then. now its to make sure I get the same data as it is in the database.